# Constant bad ping while using WiFi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, troubleshooting

[image: Bad Ping example]

So basically i have a really long house and the router is on the end of the house where my parents bedrooms are.I used a lan cable a while back and the connection issue wasnt as bad then but the cable snapped somewhere and we replaced the cable with a wifi adapter because my parents couldnt be bothered to get a new one to be extended thru the house.

To get around this issue i bought a internet adapter which i connected to the PC using a USB extension cable, in the beginning i actually used 2 different extension cables linked together because i didnt have the lenght i needed and they were lying around. The adapter was is a TP-link TL-WN722N but that system proved to be horrible, first the adapter wasnt powerful enough to catch the signal thru the walls so i had 2-3 bars connection instead of a 4 bar one and the worst part is that for some reason which i cant figure out to this day the WiFi would constantly spike in ping roughly every 5 minutes for whatever reason and in the evenings it would lag mercilessly until i decided that i have had enough and started toying with and banging the adapter up against a hard surface until it started working again or just slammed my head against my desk in despair until it decided to begin working again.

I asked my parents if they would consider moving the router a bit closer to my room which is in the opposite part of the house but they would refuese to move it because "i dont need better connection".

But recently i got a new cable that is at least as long as the two extension cables combined and its supposed to be a better quality one too , once i connected it , it seemed to give me more megabites in speed and a tiny bit of a bigger range too (because it was a bit longer then the previous two extension cables combined). So i thought it would be better in the ping compartment too...

And boy o' boy was i wrong (referring to the link at the top of the paragraph).
Now instead of giving me lag spikes it seems to stop working completely for some reason every couple of seconds.

I beg you if any of you kind people could suggest any viable solutions 
(instead of buying a powerline adapter because they dont sell those in my city and i dont have a credit/debit card or paypal account to order it online)
It would be GREATLY appreciated...

Comment: How big is the cable you're talking about? Is it protected against stepping on it? This seems like a defective cable.

Comment: its brand new from the shop its a bit longer then 2 meters

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have a choice of **2.4ghz** or **5ghz**, ***play with both*** before doing anything else.
**5** ***IS NOT*** better than **2.4**.. just different.   [They "go through stuff" differently and have different ranges.](https://support.stuff-fibre.co.nz/hc/en-us/articles/226438147-What-is-the-difference-between-2-4-GHz-and-5-GHz-)   You might find one band doesn't have this problem while the other one does.

**I fixed this exact problem for my (hardcore gamer) son.**  In my house, we could not solve this by using a different band and the router wasn't movable.

He was getting so-so wifi in his room.  His pings were slow and sometimes dropped connections.

I bought a CHEAP (like 30 bucks) wifi range extender and put it between our router and his room.
The model I bought was the "***NETGEAR Wi-Fi Range Extender EX3700***".  *I don't know* if I got lucky and picked a good brand/model or if ALL of them are good.

Don't worry about the extender not matching the branch of your router.  I have an ASUS router and a Netgear extender.

If you don't know what a range extender is:

> A Range Extender, WiFi Booster or WiFi Extender is a device that
>   repeats the wireless signal from your router to expand its coverage.
>   It functions as a bridge, capturing the WiFi from your router and
>   rebroadcasting it to areas where the WiFi is weak or nonexistent,
>   improving the performance of your home Wifi.

- I was worried that it wouldn't work.
- I was worried that his speed would be diminished greatly by the additional route.
- At least in my case.. I WAS WAY WRONG.  This product did exactly what it was supposed to do.

Good luck.